# Installing QEMU on Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: qemu

I downloaded Qemu 1.5. When I was about to configure I received this error:

> ERROR: glib-2.12 required to compile QEMU

After trying I wrote this at the command prompt: `sudo apt-get install glib2*`

It started to download a lot of stuff, I got to see references to mono and Microsoft.

At last, I could do `./configure` and make.

But I thought that qemu was less bloated than VirtualBox and others. Does qemu uses mono?

I found that glib is made in C. So, for me, it's strange that I saw those mono references. I think .NET is a wonderful technology, in certain scenarios it's useful, but if I am using Lubuntu, and Linux, I want to be away of mono, .NET and Microsoft. I just wanted to use qemu.

Answer (score 9):

The error message from `configure` is misleading.

If you run it using `bash -x` you see:

```
:
:
+ cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o /tmp/qemu-conf-14056-22808-16535.exe /tmp/qemu-conf-19869-22808-12418.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
+ return 1
+ test '' = yes
+ bluez=no
+ test no = yes
+ glib_req_ver=2.12
+ query_pkg_config --atleast-version=2.12 gthread-2.0
+ pkg-config --atleast-version=2.12 gthread-2.0
+ error_exit 'glib-2.12 required to compile QEMU'
+ echo

+ echo 'ERROR: glib-2.12 required to compile QEMU'
ERROR: glib-2.12 required to compile QEMU
+ test -n ''
+ echo

+ exit 1
+ rm -f /tmp/qemu-conf-19869-22808-12418.c /tmp/qemu-conf-12208-22808-897.o /tmp/qemu-conf-14056-22808-16535.exe
```

So you see that what is *really* missing is `gthread-2.0`. Now `gthread-2.0` is part of the `libglib2.0-dev` "Development files for the GLib library" that is not installed by default. If you install it, you should be able to get past this stage, and then probably fail because of `pixman` or something else that isn't installed, but you wont need to install *every* glib dev library!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you first compile qemu on a fresh Ubuntu, there are many pre-requisite to be installed first, the complete list / procedure is described here:

https://theintobooks.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/installing-qemu/

And to extract out from above:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install libsdl-console
sudo apt-get install libsdl-console-dev
```

and I suspect there may be more, eg, enabling libusb for usb support etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think that glib* thing might have caused lots of false positives for regex. libglib[tab] gave lot less references for me.

Comment: This is not a real answer, you might consider to write this as a comment (when you have enough reputation)